# How can I open two ports at a time as servers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, select

I'm very new to stackoverflow and socket programming.

I would like to open two server ports at a time and use them for different purpose using python3.

I could get socket **fd=3**, but finally it became **fd=-1** and **[closed]**, why?
I tried this code on RaspberryPi OS and MacOS Big Sur. The result was the same.

Please give me suggestions.

**[code]**

```py
import socket
import select

PORTS = [8080, 8081]

sockets = []

try:
  for port in PORTS:
    addr = ("0.0.0.0", port)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
      s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
      s.bind(addr)
      s.listen(1)
      print(s)
      sockets.append(s)

  print("\n\n",sockets)

  while True:
    continue

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for s in sockets:
        s.close()
```

**result**

```
python3 socket_test.py
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 8080)>
<socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 8081)>

[<socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>, <socket.socket [closed] fd=-1, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0>]
```

Comment: Why are you using `with`? Did you mean: `s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)`?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the code. It was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` statement itself ensures proper acquisition and release of resources. Since you are acquiring the socket in the `with` statement, when the `with` block is done it then releases the socket. Try this:

```
import socket
import select

PORTS = [8080, 8081]

sockets = []

try:
    for port in PORTS:
        addr = ("0.0.0.0", port)
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        s.bind(addr)
        s.listen(1)
        print(s)
        sockets.append(s)

   print("\n\n",sockets)

   while True:
       continue

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    for s in sockets:
        s.close()
```

Comment: Thank you testfile.
Resolved problem.
'with statement' was the problem.